# How do I get all values in the write file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a script that multiplies values in n-bit range. I am trying to write output values but it doesn't write all of the values.

```
from itertools import product

def multiply(res):
    output = []
    for i in res:
        output.append(bin(int(i[0], 2) * int(i[1], 2))[2:].zfill(n * 2))
    return output

arr = 0
val_x = []
val_y = []

if __name__ == "__main__":

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Enter n = '))       
            
        for x in range(n ** 2):
            for y in range(n ** 2):            
                if y == 0:
                    arr += 1
            if arr == 1:
                val_x.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
                val_y.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
            arr = 0

        res_xy = list(product(val_x, val_y))
        #print(f'Input = {res_xy}')

        res_z = (multiply(res_xy))
        for index in range(len(res_z)):
            value = res_z[index]
            print(value)
        #print(f'Output = {res_z}')

    except (ValueError, KeyError,NameError) as e:
        print(f'Invalid value or action ({e})')
        print("Please enter valid integer value")
    else:
        break

filename = "rom_<a>x<b>.dat"

for r in (('<a>', f'{2**(2*n)}'), ('<b>', f'{2*n}')):
           filename = filename.replace(*r)

fileobject = open(filename,'w')
fileobject.write(f'{(value)}')
fileobject.close()
```

When I run the script in the terminal I get all the values. For example if n=2, I get all the values from 0 to 15. But in the "rom_x.dat" file it reads only the 15th value, not the whole range. If I print "res_z" I can see all the values written, but they are in array and I need them enumerated in the write file.

Comment: In your own words, how many times do you expect the script to call `.write` on the file? What sort of thing will be written? What type is it, and how does it get its value?

Comment: "If I print "res_z" I can see all the values written, but they are in array and I need them enumerated in the write file." Okay; so the question is actually "how do I write each value from a list into a file? Well, how do you do something "with each value" in a list *any other time*?

Comment: I don't know how to help you because I can't understand the way that you talk about the code.

Comment: What is not clear in my explanation ?

Comment: For example, when you say "when I enumerate the values from the list", you're talking about the `for index in range(len(res_z)):` loop, yes? *Did you think about using a loop that looks like that, in order to make `.write` calls?* There are many ways to solve the problem but we can start with one that uses things you have already shown you know how to do.

Comment: Okay, so **in the place where you currently "take it out of the list", did you try writing it to the file instead**? I don't know how much clearer I can make this.

Comment: Clear enough, that's other approach I could have used. Thank you and I will have it in mind in future !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you generate a new value of `value` every time through the loop, and you print it at that time, but you're only writing the very last one -- whatever survives when you exit the loop.  You have two choices,  (1) open the file before the loop and do the `fileobject.write` in the loop at the same place you do the `print`, or (2) gather all the values into a list, and write the list to file after the loop.  (1) is probably easier.

** Update **

Here is method 1:

```
from itertools import product

def multiply(res):
    output = []
    for i in res:
        output.append(bin(int(i[0], 2) * int(i[1], 2))[2:].zfill(n * 2))
    return output

val_x = []
val_y = []

if __name__ == "__main__":

    filename = "rom_{0}{1}.dat"

    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Enter n = '))       
            
            name = filename.format(f'{2**(2*n)}', f'{2*n}')
            fileobject = open(name,'w')

            for x in range(n ** 2):
                arr = 0
                for y in range(n ** 2):            
                    if y == 0:
                        arr += 1
                if arr == 1:
                    val_x.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
                    val_y.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))

            res_xy = list(product(val_x, val_y))
            #print(f'Input = {res_xy}')

            res_z = (multiply(res_xy))
            for index in range(len(res_z)):
                value = res_z[index]
                print(value)
                fileobject.write(f'{value}\n')

            #print(f'Output = {res_z}')

        except (ValueError, KeyError,NameError) as e:
            print(f'Invalid value or action ({e})')
            print("Please enter valid integer value")

        fileobject.close()
```

Comment: I'm fairly new in python I just tried method (1) but It gives me errors, I don't think I understand the method well. Is it possible for an example and I will figure it out